# What is passive ARP learning and how does it work?

Tags: arp

Is it the same thing as gratuitous ARP? I cannot find any good sources on the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARP requests are sent as broadcasts - if you simply store each ARP request's source addresses in your ARP table, that's passive learning.

Gratuitous ARP is when a node sends ARP replies without anyone having sent a request.

Comment: Do you have a source? I couldn't find any by googling.

Comment: You need to improve your Google skills... https://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB31350&cat=EX3300&actp=LIST https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol#ARP_announcements